Kubernetes Cluster on Virtualbox VM - pod cannot ping Host
I am running Kubernetes cluster having one master and one worker nodes on VirtualBox VMs running in my laptop.
Laptop I.P. 10.5.48.152
Master Node I.P. 10.5.48.183
Worker Node I.P. 10.5.48.184

The nodes are able to ping each other.

Running a busybox pod in worker node.
The below command is working in the worker node.

*$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty busybox -- ping 10.5.48.184*

But the below command is not working.

*$ kubectl exec --stdin --tty busybox -- ping 10.5.48.152*

What needs to be done so that pod can ping external I.P. 10.5.48.152?


I found that the Norton Antivirus installed in my laptop had enabled a firewall which prevented the packets. I disabled the Smart Firewall of Norton Antivirus and the issue was resolved.
